# How to create 5 subplots with square aspect ratio stacked vertically in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, aspect-ratio

I want to use Matplotlib to create 5 subplots with square aspect ratio stack ed vertically. For each subplot, the x-axis has the limit from 0 to 100, and y-axis has the limit from 50 to 1000. Could someone show me how to achieve this figure?

I am new to Matplotlib and not very familiar with plotting.

Answer (score 1):

Let's address all parts of your question.

1. To create 5 subplots in a single figure and stacked vertically you can use `plt.subplots(5,1)` where the first argument is the number of rows and the second is the number of columns. So, 5 rows and 1 column means 5 plots all stacked vertically. You may also want to set the size of the figure by adding the `figsize` argument, which should be a tuple with the first argument setting the width and the second the height.
2. To make them all the same aspect ratio you will need to take each axis and call `set_aspect`, which is the ratio of x to y. Because you want 0-100 in x and 50-1000 in y you would calculate the aspect as `(100 - 0)/(1000 - 50)`.
3. To set the limits you can call the `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` methods for each of the axes where you pass the lower and upper bounds (in that order).

To do this efficiently, we can loop through all the axes and plot the data (using numpy to generate the random numbers). I also made variables for the various arguments (i.e. limits, number of points, etc.) and computed the aspect ratio.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

xlim = (0, 100)
ylim = (50, 1000)
aspect = (xlim[1]-xlim[0])/(ylim[1]-ylim[0])
N = 100

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 1, figsize=(5, 25))
for ax in axes:
    x = rng.uniform(*xlim, N)
    y = rng.uniform(*ylim, N)
    ax.plot(x, y, ".")
    ax.set_xlim(xlim)
    ax.set_ylim(ylim)
    ax.set_aspect(aspect)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

Alternatively, we can use [`plt.setp`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.setp.html) to set all the limits and aspect ratios at once for all the axes.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

xlim = (0, 100)
ylim = (50, 1000)
aspect = (xlim[1]-xlim[0])/(ylim[1]-ylim[0])
N = 100

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 1, figsize=(5, 25))
for ax in axes:
    x = rng.uniform(*xlim, N)
    y = rng.uniform(*ylim, N)
    ax.plot(x, y, ".")

plt.setp(axes, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, aspect=aspect)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

Plot result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use [set_box_aspect](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect.html)

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xlim = (0, 100)
ylim = (50, 1000)
aspect = (xlim[1]-xlim[0])/(ylim[1]-ylim[0])
N = 100

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 1, layout='constrained', figsize=(1.9,8))
for ax in axes:
    x = rng.uniform(*xlim, N)
    y = rng.uniform(*ylim, N)

    ax.plot(x, y, 'o')
    ax.set_box_aspect(1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below code is a sample that will produce 5 subplots with square aspect ratio stacked vertically:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5) = plt.subplots(5, 1, figsize=(5, 15))
fig.set_figwidth(20)

x = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=20)
y = np.random.randint(50, 1000, size=20)

ax1.set_xlim([0, 100])
ax1.set_ylim([50, 1000])
ax1.set_aspect(aspect = (0.105))
ax1.scatter(x, y)

ax2.set_xlim([0, 100])
ax2.set_ylim([50, 1000])
ax2.set_aspect(aspect = (0.105))
ax2.scatter(x, y)

ax3.set_xlim([0, 100])
ax3.set_ylim([50, 1000])
ax3.set_aspect(aspect = (0.105))
ax3.scatter(x, y)

ax4.set_xlim([0, 100])
ax4.set_ylim([50, 1000])
ax4.set_aspect(aspect = (0.105))
ax4.scatter(x, y)

ax5.set_xlim([0, 100])
ax5.set_ylim([50, 1000])
ax5.set_aspect(aspect = (0.105))
ax5.scatter(x, y)
```

and the result showed in below image:

[image]

The `aspect = (0.105)` in `set_aspect(aspect = (0.105))` method is calculated according to your x and y range. If you divide your x-range which is 100-0 by y-range that is 1000-50, you will achieve number 0.105 and this aspect ratio makes your plot square.

The line `%matplotlib inline` in code is for when you use jupyter notebook as your IDE, otherwise you don't need this line of code.